# Postgres remote connection fails on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.6

I just set up a Postgresql `v9.6.3` on AWS/EC2 and I am trying to connect to this instance from a remote location via `psql`, but I get this error...

> psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
>       Is the server running on host "ec2-<>.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (<>) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The user I am using to connect remotely was created via SQL - `CREATE ROLE my_user_name PASSWORD 'mypwd' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;` ...this user has not been created as an OS user.

This is what I have in `postgresql.conf` - `listen_addresses = '*'`

This is what I have in `pg_hba.conf` - `host   all   all   0.0.0.0/0   md5`

Comment: check security groups/VPC

Comment: Thanks yea that was it

Answer (score 0):

Check if your EC2 instance is reachable at network level. If you're trying to connect "remotely", as you said, I suppose you are trying to do it through internet. If so, ensure you have properly configured your subnet to use an Internet Gateway.

Also, you can try to simply "telnet" your EC2 instance from the remote location on the correct port, to find if the problem is at network level or it is a configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Voa Tsun suggested in the comment, it was security group issue - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html